# datatables.net with angular ts

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm using Angular 15 and I have a datatable created by datatables.net package.
there is a button in each row when it's clicked, it's expanded and a form that has more details of that row is shown. That's what I can't achieve I can't get the row element and add some functions on click on it as I don't know how the package deals with this condition.
I searched on its website but all answers are old and have classes that I can't find.
Is there anybody has used this package or at least tell me what to do? I'm completely lost.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rowCallback` attribute inside `datatable` like below:

Here dtOptions is taken as

```
dtOptions: any = {}; 

this.dtOptions = {
          data: data,
          columns: columns,
          order: [[columnNumber, 'asc']],
          rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
            const self = this;
            $('td', row).off('click');
            $('td', row).on('click', () => {
              self.rowClickedSeleted(data);
            });
            return row;
          }
        };
```

And then define `someClickHandler()` function in the component.

```
rowClickedSeleted(data: any) {
    this.getEditModelData.emit(data);
  }
```

Comment: The first part of your question relies entirely on a link. Please don’t do that. Kindly [edit] your answer to include the relevant details of that link so that your answer remains relevant even if the page that links points to is later (re)moved.